# c# call batch with error-redirect and exe over cmd via process

Tags: c#, redirect, process, batch-file, cmd

I use the following lines to create a process:

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = buildProject.DirectoryName;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

Then I start the process and pass some commands to it:

```
process.Start();

StreamWriter stream = process.StandardInput;

// call batch
stream.WriteLine(@"call ""test.bat""");

// call exe
stream.WriteLine("echo msbuild!");

// exit-command
stream.WriteLine("exit");
```

All works fine until the batchfile contains two nul-redirects:

```
@call :Jump_1
@call :Jump_2

@goto end


@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------
:Jump_1
@echo Jump_1
@call :Jump_1_1 1>nul 2>&1                   REM critical!!!
@exit /B 0

:Jump_1_1
@echo Jump_1_1
@exit /B 0


@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------
:Jump_2
@echo Jump_2
@call :Jump_2_1 1>nul 2>&1                   REM critical!!!
@exit /B 0

:Jump_2_1
@echo Jump_2_1
@exit /B 0


@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------
@echo End
:end
```

In this case the process stops immediatly. StandardOut shows this:

> Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
>
> (C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.
>
> C:\Entwicklung\ProcessTest\ProcessTest\bin\Debug>call "test.bat"
>
> Jump_1
>
> Jump_2

It only crashs if there are two Redirects if I remove one all is fine.

Because the original script is delivered with VS2010 I cannot change the script.

---

Edit: I updated the question with more details.

Comment: Will starting the .bat file as the process instead of cmd.exe not work?

Comment: no ... same problem ... even if I disable the StandardInput

Comment: Is it the redirection to nul that fails, or is it the redirection from stderror to stdout (`2>&1`)? Your code doesn't set RedirectStandardError to true...

Comment: It was the redirection from stderror to stdout. RedirectStandardError=true solves the problem. thx!

Comment: @BobVale Can you post your comment as an answer below so we can get this off the unanswered list?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it the redirection to `nul` that fails, or is it the redirection from `stderror` to `stdout (2>&1)`?

Your code doesn't set `RedirectStandardError` to true, you should set this to true and it should work.